# Getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException exception only in the Remote server?

Tags: php, laravel

I've created a web service in Laravel 5.5 for using in my Android app:

**WebServiceController.php**

```
public function GetAdvertisementList(Request $request)
{
     $data = $request->json()->all();
     return $advertisementWebServices->GetAdvertisementList($data);
}
```

With this route in **web.php**:

```
Route::post('WebService/GetAdvertisementList', 'WebServiceController@GetAdvertisementList');
```

And I've disabled the CSRF token from the **VerifyCsrfToken.php**:

```
protected $except = [
    'WebService/*'
];
```

I've tested this code with Postman and worked without any problems. but after the publishing the code, MethodNotAllowedHttpException occurred!

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please show the code that makes a request to the route.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I use Postman to send a request to http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebService/GetAdvertisementList/  with Content-Type: application/json in header and post a json object in the requset body: {"adSubjectId":"4","adSubjectConvertId":"372"} and it's worked properly in localhost.

Comment: What url in local and live you are using ? You can just share pattern not exactly the url ?

Comment: And which verb you are using ? Get or Post ? , I guess you are using get not post .

Comment: this exception happens when you are not using the method you have specified, in this example: 'POST'. you are using the wrong method to send data.

Comment: @user2486 exactly same URL except for the IP address.

Comment: @user2486 & Fatemeh-Majd, This was the first thing I checked. I definitely use the post method.

Comment: Also check route:list and middleware?

Comment: @user2486 yes, I checked the route list. I don't have any middleware for this route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u are using post from other software , use **api.web** instead of **web.api**.

In case of having web-form and using **web.api** u should also pass **{{ csrf_token() }}**.

Your route should be like this in in **api.web** :

```
Route::post('WebService/GetAdvertisementList', 'WebServiceController@GetAdvertisementList');
```

Dont forget to add "api" before your url. like this :

```
api/WebService/GetAdvertisementList
```

Plus remove "**/**" at end of url or change the route instead.